# How do I get pictures from a Nikon Coolpix p520 to a Linux system?

Tags: nikon, file-transfer, linux

I have a Nikon Coolpix p520 and just got a computer with Linux Lite. Is there a software for Linux computers so I can get my pics and video on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

This camera is supported in PTP mode (that is, plug it in via USB and transfer images) by [gPhoto](http://gphoto.org/), which is a library used by many applications, including DigiKam, Shotwell, and more. In fact, because this library is very common, I'd expect *most* programs for photo management in Linux to just work.

However, many people find it most convenient to remove the SD Card (memory card) from the camera, and put it into a reader. This is often faster and less finicky, and card readers (whether USB or built into a laptop) are almost universally Linux compatible (I can't remember the last time I found one with issues — more than a decade ago).

This camera doesn't have RAW support, so the files it produces are all in JPEG format. Many different editing tools support JPEG files, so this should be no worry.